# GLEW 1.10.0 Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glew, glfw

Why am I getting a segmentation fault when using GLEW 1.10.0 ? (I've provided details of my system at the bottom of the question.)

I downloaded and compiled GLEW. The compilation (make all) and the installation (sudo make install.all) work and show no errors. The GLEW lib is installed into /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.10.0.

I create a simple OpenGL test program (see below) that uses GLEW and glfw3 (3.0.3). When the program uses the installed GLEW lib, the segmentation fault happens. When I use the GLEW source code in my test program, the program works.

However if I load shaders and then query the compiled OpenGL program using glGetProgramInterfaceiv I again get a segmentation fault.

---

Details:

The segmentation fault happens when

1. running glewinfo
2. running visualinfo
3. test program (details below)
4. calling glGetProgramInterfaceiv (details below)

Stack trace for glewinfo using gdb

```
#0  0x00007ffff6d5fca0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff51b32f6 in __driCreateNewScreen_20050727 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#2  0x00007ffff7557c92 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff7553ea1 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff75540ce in glXChooseVisual () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#5  0x0000000000454883 in glewCreateContext ()
#6  0x000000000043b224 in main ()
```

Stack trace for visualinfo using gdb

```
#0  0x00007ffff6d5fca0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff51b32f6 in __driCreateNewScreen_20050727 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#2  0x00007ffff7557c92 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff7553ea1 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff75540ce in glXChooseVisual () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#5  0x000000000040237b in CreateContext ()
#6  0x000000000040103e in main ()
```

Below is the test program that uses the installed GLEW library and glfw3 (3.0.3)

```
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> 
int main()
{
glfwInit();
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL,
NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glewInit();
glfwTerminate();
}
```

To compile:

```
g++ -o "Basic" "main.cpp" -lglfw3 -lGLEW -lGL -lX11 -lrt -lXxf86vm -lXrandr
```

Before running ./Basic I set

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64
```

(otherwise it cannot find the GLEW lib which lives in /usr/lib64)

The program gives a segmentation fault. If I run the program through eclipse or when using gdb , the stack trace is:

```
Thread [1] 16728 [core: 2] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)    
0x7ffff65e5ca0  
__driCreateNewScreen_20050727() at 0x7ffff3de52f6   
0x7ffff7645c92  
glXQueryVersion() at 0x7ffff763d0aa 
_glfwInitContextAPI() at 0x40c580   
_glfwPlatformInit() at 0x408855 
glfwInit() at 0x404829  
main() at main.cpp:7 0x403819
```

Using gdb gives backtrace

```
#0  0x00007ffff65e5ca0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff3de52f6 in __driCreateNewScreen_20050727 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#2  0x00007ffff7980c92 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff79780aa in glXQueryVersion () from /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
#4  0x000000000040c580 in _glfwInitContextAPI ()
#5  0x0000000000408855 in _glfwPlatformInit ()
#6  0x0000000000404829 in glfwInit ()
#7  0x0000000000403819 in main ()
```

When not using the GLEW library but the source code (glew.h and glew.c) the program works. For this to work I change the first include to

```
#include <glew.h>
```

When linking this time I use the library Xi (-lXi). The g++ commands to compile and link the program are:

```
g++ -I"./" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "main.cpp"
g++ -I"./" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"glew.d" -MT"glew.d" -o "glew.o" "glew.c"
g++ -o Basic ./glew.o ./main.o -lGL -lX11 -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lrt -lglfw3 -lXi
```

Before running ./Basic I set

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

(otherwise I get the segmentation fault, because it's trying to use the installed GLEW lib )
This program does not throw the segmentation fault. The program also runs using eclipse.

---

Details when calling glGetProgramInterfaceiv(program, GL_PROGRAM_OUTPUT, GL_ACTIVE_RESOURCES, &outputs);

To the above test program I add code to load a vertex and fragment shaders. I compile the shaders into a program. This all works. Calling glGetShaderInfoLog works and prints the log. When I add a line of code that calls glGetProgramInterfaceiv the program gives a segmentation fault. Using glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; does not help.

When using gdb, I cannot get a decent stack trace. This is what gdb gives:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000042ec18 in main () at ../main.cpp:54
```

---

OS details:

- Linux: 3.2.0-4-amd64
- Distro: Debian 7.3 Wheezy
- uname -m: x86_64
- /proc/cpuinfo -> flags parameter -> lm value present

Compiler details

- g++ --version: g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

OpenGL details:

- OpenGL Provider: Advanced Micro Devices (from AMD Catalyst Control Center)
- OpenGL Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series (from AMD Catalyst Control Center)
- OpenGL Version: 4.2.11762 Compatibility Profile Context (from AMD Catalyst Control Center)
- glxinfo:
- server glx version string: 1.4
- client glx version string: 1.4
- GLX version: 1.4
- OpenGL version string: 4.2.11762 Compatibility Profile Context
- OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20
- server glx vendor string: ATI
- client glx vendor string: ATI

Details for the libraries used in the test program
 - -lglfw /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a 3.0.3

- -lGL there are 2 on my system libGL.so.1.2 -> /usr/lib64/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2 and libGL.so.1.2 -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2
- -lX11 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
- -lrt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
- -lXrandr /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 -> libXrandr.so.2.2.0
- -lXxf86vm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 -> libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
- -lXi /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 -> libXi.so.6.1.0

Comment: You should use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: I added the strack trace from gdb. How else can gdb help ?

Comment: I'm guessing, but could it be a 32bit vis 64bit issue? The stack traces show the problem occurs in libc.so.6 and I have 2 versions of these (one in /lib32/libc-2.13.so and another in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so) ?

Comment: why are you ignoring the return value of `glewInit`?

Comment: @legends2k, yes the return value should be check. The segmentation fault happens when calling glfwInit (i.e. before the call to glewinit).

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling: the cause is a mix-up between  pure 64bit libs and 32bit libs.

Concerning: segmentation fault

If

1. move libGLEW out of /usr/lib64 (e.g. into /tmp folder) and
2. then e.g. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp (instead of export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64)

then the segmentation faults go away (test program runs, glewinfo and visualinfo work)

Something  in /usr/lib64 is causing the problem.

I came across this page [AMD 13.1 64 bit drivers and the libGL.so.1 error](http://steveoliveira.com/blog/amd-13-1-64-bit-drivers-and-the-libgl-so-1-error/) which explains where the AMD installer puts the libGL.so file

> the installer puts lib files in /usr/lib64. However, if you have Ubuntu, the 64 bit libraries go in /usr/lib. I did the following to fix my problem.
>
> Uninstall the driver
>   sudo ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --uninstall
>
> Remove the /usr/lib64 folder
>   sudo rm -Rf /usr/lib64
>
> Create a symbolic link /usr/lib64 which points to /lib/usr
>   sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64
>
> Install the driver again
>   sudo ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --force
>
> Reboot
>   sudo reboot

I'm not sure if that symbolic link is a good idea or not...

---

Concerning: [glGetProgramInterfaceiv (GLAPI/glGetProgramInterface)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramInterface)

fails because it's only available from OpenGL >= 4.3. My card is 4.2. Running glewinfo also reveals this:

```
GL_ARB_program_interface_query:                                MISSING 
-------------------------------
glGetProgramInterfaceiv:                                     MISSING
glGetProgramResourceIndex:                                   MISSING
glGetProgramResourceLocation:                                MISSING
glGetProgramResourceLocationIndex:                           MISSING
glGetProgramResourceName:                                    MISSING
glGetProgramResourceiv:                                      MISSING
```